# How can I see the desktop of locked server

Tags: windows

Is there a way to view the desktop of a locked server? 
i.e. not really use a screen saver.

I'm looking to be able to walk by a server and see diagnostic screens and scrolling log files but have the keyboard locked as a security measure.

I see that Microsoft had a Clear Screen saver in the Windows 2000 server resource kit but, I also found that it had problems with more that one monitor.

[Clear Screen Saver Does Not Work On Multi-Monitor Workstations](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287020)

Answer (score 3):

[Transparant Screen Lock](http://www.e-motional.com/TScreenLock.htm) seems to be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I will fully admit, I don't know how to do this, but it could be a step in the right direction.  On Windows the locked screen is really nothing more than a screen with nothing on it overlayed on top of the main screen (the screen you see when you are logged in).  It's possible to modify windows so the locked screen is not the screen on top (or in front etc.).  You can modify it so your diagnostic screen is above the lock screen if that makes sense.  I've seen it done before, but I am not certain of the exact procedure.  I would guess it's a change somewhere in the registry, but I don't know.